# Automating Thick client, Web application and mobile apps with a single tool

Tags: testing, automated-tests

I have a scenario where I need to automate all the applications A Windows thick client, a web application and a mobile application. Any single tool I can use for this? if not any combination?

The scenario will go as follows:

Thick client (output) --> Web Application --> (output) --> Mobile app --> (output) --> Assert()

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there's no single tool to do this as you probably know some of the tools you have at your disposal : Selenium WebDriver, Appium, [Various Tools for Thick Client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/using-ui-automation-for-automated-testing), etc .... [Similar question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6209/free-tools-to-test-both-windows-desktop-apps-and-web-apps-interconnected)

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend you HP Load Runner tools set.
I am not sure if you can combine all of these but you should be able i guess.
You can also try trial version. It works like premium version but there is a limitation for VUs up to 50. Also if you create some scenario in trial version you can use it in premium.